# jQuery Sparkline is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, sparklines

I tried to emulate the example provided by https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs, since I want to work with JQuery Sparklines for a project.

**This is what my attempt displays**

[image]

I downloaded the `jquery.sparkline.js` file from their website and reference it in my code. Same thing with `jquery.js`, I installed this one with `npm` and added the file to my project folder.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        /** This code runs when everything has been loaded on the page */
        /* Inline sparklines take their values from the contents of the tag */
        $('.inlinesparkline').sparkline(); 
 
        /* Sparklines can also take their values from the first argument 
        passed to the sparkline() function */
        var myvalues = [10,8,5,7,4,4,1];
        $('.dynamicsparkline').sparkline(myvalues);
 
        /* The second argument gives options such as chart type */
        $('.dynamicbar').sparkline(myvalues, {type: 'bar', barColor: 'green'} );
 
        /* Use 'html' instead of an array of values to pass options 
        to a sparkline with data in the tag */
        $('.inlinebar').sparkline('html', {type: 'bar', barColor: 'red'} );
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
Inline Sparkline: <span class="inlinesparkline">1,4,4,7,5,9,10</span>.
</p>
<p>
Sparkline with dynamic data: <span class="dynamicsparkline">Loading..</span>
</p>
<p>
Bar chart with dynamic data: <span class="dynamicbar">Loading..</span>
</p>
<p>
Bar chart with inline data: <span class="inlinebar">1,3,4,5,3,5</span>
</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Taking your code as-is and using CDN links to jquery/sparklines, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ewry84dc/   could be how you copied it locally  Or your local path is incorrect.   Look for console errors (F12) eg (`$ not defined`) or `404 jquery.js not found`

Comment: Weirdly I seem to be having the 404 jquery.js not found, even though I can swear the path is correct. Even tried switching it up and nothing works. 
The links you used are working for me tho, so until I find a solution I'll use these, thanks :)